AR js use front camera on mobile
I develop a virtual sunglass try-on app. Everything ok on desktop, but i unable to use front camera on mobile.
Here is my full code:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Face Tracking with AR.js</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AR-js-org/AR.js@3.3.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        #controls { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 10; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
    <a-marker-camera preset="hiro"></a-marker-camera>

    <!-- Static model before face tracking starts -->
    <a-entity id="sunglassesModel" gltf-model="https://apollocdn-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/tryon/coolly/Coolley.gltf"
              scale="0.005 0.005 0.005" position="0 1.5 -2" rotation="0 0 0" visible="true">
    </a-entity>

    <!-- Use a face tracking anchor -->
    <a-entity id="faceAnchor" arjs-face-anchor>
        <a-entity id="faceSunglassesModel" gltf-model="https://apollocdn-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/tryon/coolly/Coolley.gltf"
                  scale="0.005 0.005 0.005" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" visible="false">
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>

<div id="controls">
    <button onclick="changeModel('https://apollocdn-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/tryon/coolly/Coolley.gltf')">Sunglasses 1</button>
    <button onclick="changeModel('https://apollocdn-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/tryon/generous/Generous.gltf')">Sunglasses 2</button>
    <button onclick="changeModel('https://apollocdn-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/tryon/posh/Posh.gltf')">Sunglasses 3</button>
</div>

<script>
    async function initFrontCamera() {
        const constraints = {
            video: {
                facingMode: { ideal: 'user' }, // Front camera
                width: { ideal: 1280 },
                height: { ideal: 720 }
            }
        };

        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
            const video = document.createElement('video');
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
            video.setAttribute('muted', '');
            video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
            document.body.appendChild(video);

            // Wait for the video stream to be ready
            video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                const arSystem = document.querySelector('a-scene').systems['arjs'];
                arSystem.sourceElement = video;
                arSystem._initSource = function () {
                    this.context.arController.setVideo(video);
                    this.context.arController.setup(video);
                };
                arSystem.start();
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error accessing front camera:', error);
        }
    }

    window.onload = () => {
        initFrontCamera();
    };

    function changeModel(url) {
        console.log('Changing model to: ' + url);
        const sunglassesEntity = document.querySelector('#faceSunglassesModel');
        sunglassesEntity.setAttribute('gltf-model', url);
    }

    // Handle face tracking state
    AFRAME.registerComponent('arjs-face-anchor', {
        init: function () {
            this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('markerFound', (event) => {
                console.log('Face marker found');
                const faceSunglassesModel = document.querySelector('#faceSunglassesModel');
                faceSunglassesModel.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
                const staticSunglassesModel = document.querySelector('#sunglassesModel');
                staticSunglassesModel.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            });

            this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('markerLost', (event) => {
                console.log('Face marker lost');
                const faceSunglassesModel = document.querySelector('#faceSunglassesModel');
                faceSunglassesModel.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
                const staticSunglassesModel = document.querySelector('#sunglassesModel');
                staticSunglassesModel.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
            });

            this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('faceUpdate', (event) => {
                const face = event.detail;
                const sunglassesModel = document.getElementById('faceSunglassesModel');
                if (face && sunglassesModel) {
                    const leftEye = face.getLandmark('leftEye');
                    const rightEye = face.getLandmark('rightEye');
                    const nose = face.getLandmark('noseTip');

                    if (leftEye && rightEye && nose) {
                        const eyeDistance = Math.sqrt(
                            Math.pow(rightEye.x - leftEye.x, 2) +
                            Math.pow(rightEye.y - leftEye.y, 2) +
                            Math.pow(rightEye.z - leftEye.z, 2)
                        );

                        console.log('Eye Distance:', eyeDistance);

                        const baseScale = 0.005;
                        const scaleFactor = eyeDistance / 300;
                        const scale = baseScale * scaleFactor;
                        sunglassesModel.object3D.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);

                        const eyeMidPoint = {
                            x: (leftEye.x + rightEye.x) / 2,
                            y: (leftEye.y + rightEye.y) / 2,
                            z: (leftEye.z + rightEye.z) / 2,
                        };

                        sunglassesModel.object3D.position.set(eyeMidPoint.x, eyeMidPoint.y - (eyeDistance / 2), eyeMidPoint.z);

                        const rotationY = Math.atan2(rightEye.y - leftEye.y, rightEye.x - leftEye.x);
                        sunglassesModel.object3D.rotation.set(0, rotationY, 0);

                        console.log('Adjusted Model scale:', sunglassesModel.object3D.scale);
                        console.log('Adjusted Model position:', sunglassesModel.object3D.position);
                        console.log('Adjusted Model rotation:', sunglassesModel.object3D.rotation);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

i try facingMode: { ideal: 'user' } or facingMode: { ideal: '-webkit-user' } nothing worked. when the page load the app uses front camera, but when is fully loaded it will switch back to the back camera.
